# Name variables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Refer: How you name variables in Laravel & PHP.

> $firstName or $first_name?
>
> $userid or $userId or $user_id?

Comment: Commonly asked and debated question.  My opinion is that whatever you do, continue to do.  No code is uglier than code that doesn't follow its own rules.  I like using underscores for the less important variables so `first_name` and `user_id`..for data models like I use capitals, so `Account` or `User`.  But sometimes I do camel case for less important data models, like `previousUser`.  All in all, its habits and convention.  There is no necessarily right or wrong way for variables.

Answer (score 9):

[PSR-1 Coding Standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md) have this to say:

> Whatever naming convention is used SHOULD be applied consistently within a reasonable scope. That scope may be vendor-level, package-level, class-level, or method-level.

Personally I use mixedCase for properties and underscored separated for variables defined in a function, method or in global scope.

The important thing is to use it consistently so that you will be able to readily tell if a variable is being misused (i.e. I know if I see a camel cased variable without an object operator I know it is an error).

Larvel 4's [coding guidelines](http://four.laravel.com/docs/contributing#coding-guidelines) state that they adhere to PSR-1 with no mention of the representation of variables.

Comment: why is this down-voted?  It's pretty much what I said in a comment..but quotes PSR, so is worthy of an answer. IMO

Comment: Probably downvoted because they didn't like my preference, but I only stated it to illustrate the importance of consistency.

Comment: Doesn't that become a problem when you are accessing properties of an eloquent object? Since table columns are snake_case?

Answer (score 5):

```
Laravel 3: $first_name
Laravel 4: $firstName
```

Why? Cause you following the framework convention makes your code easier too read for other developers which join the project later.

Thats not my personal prefer. Thats what the crowd hopefully do. :)

Comment: Is that for variables or properties or both?

Comment: Its for both. In Laravel its also for methods.
Example: 

  ... $this->has_one() - L3 ...
  $this->hasOne() - L4

Comment: It they have officially adopted one over the other then they should post it with their coding guidelines.

Comment: One thing that should be mentioned also is that Eloquent only have snake case support for column names in the database. But in the code they are accessible with both snake and camel case.